# Correct use of findall/3, especially the first template argument

Tags: prolog, prolog-findall

i know there is a build-in function findall/3 in prolog,
and im trying to find the total numbers of hours(Thrs) and store them in a list, then sum the list up. but it doesnt work for me. here is my code:

```
totalLecHrs(LN,THrs) :-
    lecturer(LN,LId),
    findall(Thrs, lectureSegmentHrs(CC,LId,B,E,THrs),L),
    sumList(L,Thrs).
```

could you tell me what's wrong with it? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a "dummy" variable for Hours in the **findall/3** subgoal.  What you wrote uses THrs both as the return value for **sumList/2** and as the variable to be listed in L by **findall/3**.  Use X as the first argument of findall and in the corresponding subgoal **lectureSegmentHrs/5** as the last argument.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that you're using the same variable (`Thrs`) twice for different things. However it's hard to tell as you've also used different capitalisation in different places. Change the `findall` line so that the initial variable has the same capitalisation in the `lectureSegmentHrs` call. Then use a different variable completely to get the final output value (ie the one that appears in `sumList` and in the return slot of the entire predicate).

You need to use a different variable because Prolog does not support variable reassignment. In a logical language, the notion of reassigning a variable is inherently impossible. Something like the following may seem sensible...

```
...
X = 10,
X = 11,
...
```

But you have to remember that `,` in Prolog is the conjunction operator. You're effectively telling Prolog to find a solution to your problem where X is both 10 and 11 at the *same time*. So it's obviously going to tell you that that can't be done.

Instead you have to just make up new variable names as you go along. Sometimes this does get a bit annoying but it's just goes with the territory of a logical languages.