# why findall/3 in swi-prolog ignores variable binding?

Tags: prolog, prolog-setof, prolog-findall

The following codes give these results:

```
?- X = a, findall(Element, ( member(Z, [a,b,c]), Element = Z:X  ), Set).
X = a,
Set = [a:a, b:a, c:a].
```

But when I want that all elements will share the same unbound variable (instead of a), then things are not working as it is supposed:

```
?- X = Y, findall(Element, ( member(Z, [a,b,c]), Element = Z:X  ), Set).
X = Y,
Set = [a:_G1918, b:_G1912, c:_G1906].
```

Why _G1918, _G1912, and _G1906 are not bound to each other?
is that a bug in swi-prolog?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305833/correct-use-of-findall-3-especially-the-first-template-argument ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `bagof/3` for that:

```
?- X = Y, bagof(Element, Z^( member(Z, [a,b,c]), Element = Z:X  ), Set).
X = Y,
Set = [a:Y, b:Y, c:Y].
```

From SWI-Prolog's documentation:

> findall/3 is equivalent to bagof/3 with all free variables bound with
>   the existential operator (^), except that bagof/3 fails when Goal has
>   no solutions.

In your query `X` is a free variable, so the result you get is the same with the one for `bagof/3` with `X^`:

```
?- X = Y, bagof(Element, X^Z^( member(Z, [a,b,c]), Element = Z:X  ), Set).
X = Y,
Set = [a:_G2115, b:_G2109, c:_G2103].
```

Comment: Thanks for noting a connection between findall/3 and bagof/3. Working all the time with findall/3 now bagof/3 seems very unintuitive.

Answer (score 1):

it's not a bug, the 'all solutions' builtins differs in variable quantification handling.

findall/3 it's the simpler model. For your case, bagof/3 will work, but you'll need to indicate the aggregation variable:

```
?- X = Y, bagof(Element, Z^( member(Z, [a,b,c]), Element = Z:X  ), Set).
X = Y,
Set = [a:Y, b:Y, c:Y].
```

Comment: Thanks it works. The output is what I need but don't understand how it works. http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=allsolutions says that: +Var^Goal tells bagof/3 not to bind Var in Goal. Also unclear. The problem was in X that it was not bind; and it is solved by telling not to bind Z? but binding of Z was ok.
Please could you explain more?

Comment: Ok, I got the answer from @Tudor Berariu 's answer on the question.

Comment: yes, Tudor explained a bit more. The documentation could be more clear. I think of this problem as a different term copying behaviour (findall doesn't keep 'external to goal' variables sharing)